# Automate Document Moving and Metadata Entry with SharePoint Online and Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I would like to understand if the following use case is possible within SharePoint Online and MS Flow.

- I have a Document Library in Associated Site of a Hub Site where I would like a user to be able to run a Flow on a Folder full of documents.
- When the flow is triggered the user is prompted to enter 4 required metadata fields
- Once the metadata is entered, the Folder and all its documents are moved to a Document Library in the Hub Site (which will have matching metadata fields).

Is such a solution feasible using SP Online and Flow?

Thanks

Comment: A PowerApp, rather than flow, might be better suited

Comment: Thank you for your comment, could you please elaborate as to why a PowerApp might be better suited?

Comment: Just a suggestion since your are using 'documents in a folder' : have you looked into whether document sets would be an even better structure ?

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen Yes I have considered this, however people are used to folders and heavy users of the sync feature. Does Document Sets make the above use case easier?

Comment: Being a consultant: it depends ;-) however since document sets are just folders with metadata it might make it a lot easier. If the reason for moving the folder is related to the approval state of the docs in the folder then that requirement could be handled by the metadata for the document set. Document sets are about to be a full member of the modern SharePoint family: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Update-Document-Sets-in-Modern-Document-Libraries/td-p/464058

Comment: The more and more I think about this, document sets could be the way forward. The only issue is you need someone to create the document set first, enter metadata and then they can drag and drop the files via the Sync client, which is a nice user experience.

I just wonder if there is a way to click a button from within the document library of the  site associated to the hub site, it then brings up the new document set screen from the hub site.. this removes the need for the user to navigate to the hub site, then to the document library, selecting a new document set.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy to achieve although some things with Flow are bit convoluted. 
SO first you need to create a Flow with the start data (your required fields) Then you query for all items inside of the flow. Then using that collection (and for each action) you update the metadata, then again using same collection you use the copy action, if the copy action was successful then you delete the items in the source folder (or source folder itself) one problem is that Flow designer forgot that you can have folders in the library and actions don't work on them (at least last time I tried) so you will need to use Rest calls to SharePoint API to work with them. There are plenty of examples on the Net how to use Rest calls. Important point is to delete items only if the copy was successful, in my experience some actions fail. We have one Flow that imports some items on a daily basis and from time to time it fails to create 1 or 2 items out of 3k (and the reason is that it couldn't find target list (SIC!) in that case we perform manual intervention.

Comment: Can you explain how the user experience would be for a user? what I imagine, is that the user would click a folder in a document library then click a button "archive this file" which then takes them to a form where they have to add the required metadata.. after which the folder and all its contents are copied to another document library with the same metadata as the form.

Comment: From what I could tell... the "Flow dropdown button" only appears when you select a File but not when you select a Folder... I need that to appear for a Folder within a Folder specifically.